# How to have several MIC listeners at the same time

Tags: android, audio-recording, microphone, android-mediarecorder, android-audiorecord

I have class A which uses `AudioRecorder` instance for getting audio amplitude level. Also I have a class B where I want to record an audio to amr every 5 minutes.

How can I use both functionalities at the same time ? As far as I know, at the certain time only one object can have an access to the `MIC`.